# Filters of Primefaces Tree do not work well with more than 10 nodes

Tags: primefaces

Filters of Primefaces Tree do not work with more than 10 nodes in the root

```
<p:tree filterBy="#{node}"
        filterMatchMode="contains"
        id="treeEstruc" 
        styleClass="Wid100" 
        value="#{patrimonioController.root}"
        var="node" 
        selectionMode="single" 
        selection="#{patrimonioController.selectedNode}">
    <p:ajax event="select" process="@this" update=":mainFrm:panelDatalles"
            oncomplete="PF('patrimonios').clearFilters();"
            listener="#{patrimonioController.onNodeSelect}" />
    <p:ajax event="unselect" listener="#{patrimonioController.onNodeUnselect}"
            update=":mainFrm:panelDatalles"/>
    <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
        <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I am thinking that I have done everything correct and that problems from the library, I am using version 6.1.1

Comment: What doesn't work specifically?

Comment: no work filter fine and no error show. Also I found this  https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1798

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue will be fixed in primefaces version 6.2
[Link to primefaces issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2301)